# nopcommerce email settings - port 465 SSL not being honoured

Tags: azure, nopcommerce

I am trying to configure email settings with NOP3.7.  My settings are as follows:

[image]

For some reason the port 465 is not being honoured and it tries to connect on port 25.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Now we know that your password is •••••••••••••

Comment: Which is your host provider? and did you checked system log?

Comment: If you're sure about that, best course of action would be sending an issue report to nopCommerce.

Comment: My host provider is Namecheap.  The system log says: http://pastebin.com/DPELrnWH

Comment: @fcuk112 Could you check to flushed the server dns cache.